# The inverse Laplace Transform of a real proper rational function must be real

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, complex, integral-transforms

How does one get *Mathematica* to return a real answer when using `InverseLaplaceTransform`? Tried using `Re` and `ComplexExpand` to no avail. The inverse of a real rational function must be real (it is a real system). For example:

```
InverseLaplaceTransform[(s^2 + 3.0)/(s^5 + 3 s^4 + 6 s^3 + 6 s^2 + 3 s^2 + 2 s + 10), s, t]
```

returns a complex mess.

Comment: `ComplexExpand` worked fine for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, it is best to use exact numbers with symbolic methods. The approximate number `3.0` is disguising the situation.

With `3.0` changed to 3:

```
InverseLaplaceTransform[(s^2 + 3)/(s^5 + 3 s^4 + 6 s^3 + 6 s^2 + 3 s^2 + 2 s + 10), s, t]

(* Long result in terms of algebraic numbers *)

% // N // Chop

(* -0.000165958 (-1019.4 2.71828^(-2.29182 t) + (185.397 - 
    339.966 I) 2.71828^((-0.651002 - 1.91236 I) t) + (185.397 + 
    339.966 I) 2.71828^((-0.651002 + 1.91236 I) t) + (324.304 - 
    498.343 I) 2.71828^((0.29691 - 0.990481 I) t) + (324.304 + 
    498.343 I) 2.71828^((0.29691 + 0.990481 I) t)) *)
```

In this form, you can see that the imaginary parts of the complex coefficients cancel.

Added 10/19:

You can have an explicitly real formula in the approximate numerical domain:

```
InverseLaplaceTransform[(s^2 + 3)/(s^5 + 3 s^4 + 6 s^3 + 6 s^2 + 
    3 s^2 + 2 s + 10), s, t] // 
    N // ComplexExpand // Simplify // Chop
(* 0.169178 E^(-2.29182 t) - 0.107642 E^(0.29691 t) Cos[0.990481 t] - 
0.0615362 E^(-0.651002 t) Cos[1.91236 t] +
0.165408 E^(0.29691 t) Sin[0.990481 t] + 
0.11284 E^(-0.651002 t) Sin[1.91236 t] *)
```

But I think most of us who actually use this math are used to working with complex natural frequencies.

> The shortest path between two truths in the real domain passes through the complex domain.

-- Jacques Hadamard

Comment: Seems that Mathematica is having trouble getting back to the real domain here.

Comment: @Jim Mathematica yields a real result expressed in terms of complex constants. This is common in algebra, and a fine example of Hadamard's maxim.

Comment: Yeah, but I still think it should make it real with no complex constants.